# Shared libraries in glassfish using maven

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, shared-libraries

I need to setup a shared library in a glassfish server using maven to avoid a huge generated ear when I need to deploy my application.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create an archive of the dependencies you need to create the **shared-library artifacts** together.